# Julia Set - Cuda , improve the performance failed

Tags: performance, cuda

Recently I am learning the examples in the book CUDA by JASON SANDERS.
the example of Juila Set makes a bad performance of 7032ms.
Here is the program:

```
#include <cuda.h>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <cpu_bitmap.h>
#include <book.h>
#define DIM 1024

struct cuComplex{
    float r;
    float i;
    __device__ cuComplex(float a, float b) : r(a),i(b){

    }
    __device__ float magnitude2(void){
        return r*r+i*i;
    }
    __device__ cuComplex operator *(const cuComplex& a){
        return cuComplex(r*a.r-i*a.i, i*a.r+r*a.i);
    }
    __device__ cuComplex operator +(const cuComplex& a){
        return cuComplex(r+a.r,i+a.i);
    }
};

__device__ int julia(int x,int y){
    const float scale = 1.5;
    float jx = scale * (float)(DIM/2 - x)/(DIM/2);
    float jy = scale * (float)(DIM/2 - y)/(DIM/2);

    cuComplex c(-0.8,0.156);
    cuComplex a(jx,jy);

    int i = 0;
    for(i = 0; i<200; i++){
        a = a*a + c;
        if(a.magnitude2() > 1000){
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}

__global__ void kernel(unsigned char *ptr){
    int x = blockIdx.x;
    int y = blockIdx.y;
    int offset = x + y*gridDim.x;

    int juliaValue = julia(x,y);
    ptr[offset*4 + 0] = 255*juliaValue;
    ptr[offset*4 + 1] = 0;
    ptr[offset*4 + 2] = 1;
    ptr[offset*4 + 3] = 255;

}




int main(void){

    CPUBitmap bitmap(DIM,DIM);
    unsigned char * dev_bitmap;

    dim3 grid(DIM,DIM);
    dim3 blocks(DIM/16,DIM/16);
    dim3 threads(16,16);
    dim3 thread(DIM,DIM);
    cudaEvent_t start,stop;
    cudaEvent_t bitmapCpy_start,bitmapCpy_stop;
    HANDLE_ERROR(cudaEventCreate(&start));
    HANDLE_ERROR(cudaEventCreate(&stop));
    HANDLE_ERROR(cudaEventCreate(&bitmapCpy_start));
    HANDLE_ERROR(cudaEventCreate(&bitmapCpy_stop));

    HANDLE_ERROR(cudaMalloc((void **)&dev_bitmap,bitmap.image_size()));

    HANDLE_ERROR(cudaEventRecord(start,0));


    kernel<<<grid,1>>>(dev_bitmap);

    HANDLE_ERROR(cudaMemcpy(bitmap.get_ptr(),dev_bitmap,bitmap.image_size(),cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
    //HANDLE_ERROR(cudaEventRecord(bitmapCpy_stop,0));
    //HANDLE_ERROR(cudaEventSynchronize(bitmapCpy_stop));
//  float copyTime;
//  HANDLE_ERROR(cudaEventElapsedTime(&copyTime,bitmapCpy_start,bitmapCpy_stop));

    HANDLE_ERROR(cudaEventRecord(stop,0));
    HANDLE_ERROR(cudaEventSynchronize(stop));
    float elapsedTime;
    HANDLE_ERROR(cudaEventElapsedTime(&elapsedTime,start,stop));



    //printf("Total time is %3.1f ms, time for copying is %3.1f ms \n",elapsedTime,copyTime);
    printf("Total time is %3.1f ms\n",elapsedTime);

    bitmap.display_and_exit();
    HANDLE_ERROR(cudaEventDestroy(start));
    HANDLE_ERROR(cudaEventDestroy(stop));
    HANDLE_ERROR(cudaEventDestroy(bitmapCpy_start));
    HANDLE_ERROR(cudaEventDestroy(bitmapCpy_stop));
    HANDLE_ERROR(cudaFree(dev_bitmap));
}
```

I think the main factor that influences the performance is that the program above just run 1 thread in every block:

```
 kernel<<<grid,1>>>(dev_bitmap);
```

so I change the kernel like the following:

```
__global__ void kernel(unsigned char *ptr){

    int x = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x*blockDim.x;
    int y = threadIdx.y + blockIdx.y*blockDim.y;

    int offset = x + y*gridDim.x*blockIdx.x;

    int juliaValue = julia(x,y);
    ptr[offset*4 + 0] = 255*juliaValue;
    ptr[offset*4 + 1] = 0;
    ptr[offset*4 + 2] = 1;
    ptr[offset*4 + 3] = 255;

}
```

and call kernel:

```
dim3 blocks(DIM/16,DIM/16);
dim3 threads(16,16);
kernel<<<blocks,threads>>>(dev_bitmap);
```

I think this change is not a big deal, but when I ran it, it acted like that it ran into some endless loops, no image appeared and I couldn't do anything with my screen， just blocked there.

toolkit: cuda 5.5

system: ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I run the original code you have posted here, I get a correct display and a time of ~340ms.

When I make your kernel change, I get an "unspecified launch error" on the kernel launch.

In your modified kernel, you have the following which is an incorrect computation:

```
int offset = x + y*gridDim.x*blockIdx.x;
```

When I change it to:

```
int offset = x + y*gridDim.x*blockDim.x;
```

I get normal execution and results, and an indicated time of ~10ms.

Comment: thank you, that's it.I have found the error and ran it correctly,

Comment: WOW, your GPU is much faster than mine, I jsut got a 290.8ms performance, and my GPU is Geforce 9800T, how about yours?

Comment: For this test I was running on a Quadro1000M (notebook PC) GPU.